# how to convert series of numbers into 0 to 10 range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a large series of numbers that I want to convert to a 0 to 10 scale.

I used the following formula to convert the maximum value to 10 and minimum value to 0,

```
=IF(A1="-","0",MIN(MAX((A1-MIN(A:A))/((MAX(A:A)-MIN(A:A))/11),0),10))
```

However,I face some problems converting the series where maximum value should be 0 and minimum value should be 10. For example, if column A has the values,

1
4
6
7
8

then 8 should have a value of 0 and 1 should have a value of 10.

Thanks!

Comment: `=10-IF(A1="-","0",MIN(MAX((A1-MIN(A:A))/((MAX(A:A)-MIN(A:A))/11),0),10))`?

Comment: Yes but why is OP dividing by 11? Shouldn't it be 10?

Comment: Thanks, @jsheeran. Since I am including missing values in the calculation, I made a small modification to your proposed formula that seems to be working for me. 

=IF(A1="-","0",10-MIN(MAX((A1-MIN(A:A))/((MAX(A:A)-MIN(A:A))‌​/10),0),10))

Answer (score 3):

Just use the formula =10-B1, where B1 is the cell containing your mentioned formula.

Please note though that your formula has the following flaws:

1. It is wrong. If you test it with the three numbers 1,2,3 you get 5.5 for the value corresponding to 2. Obviously the correct answer should be 5. This error is caused by the number 11 that you use to divide the (MAX(A:A)-MIN(A:A)). Change it to 10 and everything will work!
2. It returns #DIV/0! if you have only one number in column A.
3. It is inefficient because it calls time-expensive functions MAX(A:A) and MIN(A:A) in each and every cell containing this formula. Since these two functions are not dependent on the formula-containing cell, consider using them only once in some other cells and subsequently modify your formula so it contains links to these external cells rather than the functions themselves.
4. It is hardly maintainable and/or readable. It took me a while to understand how your formula works. Consider separating it into meaningful pieces, place the pieces into separate cells and finally simply link the pieces together in some final - and much smaller - formula.
5. It is unnecessarily convoluted. There is a much easier formula to achieve the same thing, based on the following:

= 10*B1/C1,

where B1 contains the "distance from minimum", i.e. A1-MIN(A:A), and C1 contains the total length of your range of numbers, i.e. MAX(A:A)-MIN(A:A)

Comment: Thanks, Tom. That 11 was a mistake, changed it to 10. Some reasoning behind using this formula: I have multiple columns that I need to normalize from 0 to 10. For some columns, "higher values= better" and for the rest, "lower values= better". I also wanted to assign 0 (the lowest value) to empty cells/cells without a value. Copy pasting this formula to columns adjacent to the ones that I need to convert makes things a bit easier for me. Hope that makes sense.